# Determining the time complexity of these nested loops

Tags: big-o

```
for i = 1 to n do
    j = i
    while j < n do
        j = 2 * j
```

The answer given to me is O(n) because the sum from i=1 to n of 1 + log(n/i) is the amount of times it runs. Could someone explain how to get to that conclusion? I know the outer loops runs O(n), but how do I get what I need from the inner loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, external loop will obviously do `n` iterations.

What internal loop does, is basically multiplying `j` by `2` while it is less then `n`, so for first iteration `j=1` it will multiply it `1 + log(n)` in worst case. For more general case `j=i`, where `1 <= i < n` you will need `1 + log(n)-log(i)` times (as you start not from 1 but from `i`). `1 + log(n)-log(i)= 1 + log(n/i)`.

So all in all you have `O(sum (1 + log(n/i)) from 1 to n)` which eventually is [equal](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20(1%20%2B%20log_2(n%2Fi))%20for%20i%20%3D%201%20to%20n) to `O(n + c*log(n))` where `c`is some constant factor, and using big-O rules, we don't care about `log(n)` part, because we have `n` part, so its just `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You end up with

```
        n
T(n) = Sum ( log(n/i) )
       i=1

        n
     = Sum ( log(n) - log(i) )
       i=1

    =  n log n - log(n!)
```

Use [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to replace `log(n!) = n log n - n + O(log n)`

```
T(n) = n - O(log n) = O(n)
```